# Using RegExp to find whitespace or newline of a url using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to test when user keypresses on a input to check the string for a url with a trailing whitespace or newline.

So to trigger if **"google.com "** so can run a function after typed (as gets cut off on **"google.co"** and triggers).

```
if(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)/?").test($("#text_area").html())) {
        alert("url inside");
    }
```

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do that in JavaScript without RegExp. Use [.trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/jsref_trim_string.asp):

```
if($("#text_area").html().trim() != $("#text_area").html()) {
    alert("url inside");
}
```

Comment: using trim would not work to well this this as using for a posting status like twitter or facebook and looking for URL's in status update to get web URL and get og:content

Answer (score -1):

It's fine, I have figured it out myself, thanks for the help but was testing a status update and needed to check the user has finished typing the URL for looking for **"webdomain.com "** or the RegExp would find **"webdomain.co"** on keyup before the user had finished typing the full URL.

Anyone else looking for the same thing, will need this kind of code (only spaces, not newlines though)

```
if(new RegExp("([a-zA-Z0-9]+://)?([a-zA-Z0-9_]+:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@)?([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})(:[0-9]+)?([\\s])").test($("#text_area").html())) {
      alert("url inside");  
    }
```